# BLE Characteristic not retained

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am writing an application which communicates with multiple (between 5 & 10) identical BLE devices. Each BLE device has multiple characteristics some are static, some update and others can be written to.

The application has multiple ViewControllers embedded within a Navigation Controller and is for IOS devices (specifically IOS 8+ and iPhone 6).

In order to make the program efficient and to work with CoreBluetooth I have created to classes to manage the BLE interaction:

1. BLE Control Class - Which scans for and connects the correct BLE devices.

and

2. BLE Services Class - Once connected scans the characteristics and sets them appropriately according to their type.

Data sent by a peripheral and received by the manager for known connected characteristics is then stored in a back-end SQLite db.

The issue I am facing is writing back to a connected peripherals characteristic. I have collected the characteristic within a CBCharacteristic, but it does not persist within the class when I attempt to write to it the value of the CBCharacteristic is NULL.

Following is a summary of the code I have used:

CBCharacteristic Definition within the BLEServicesClass

```
#import "BLEServicesClass.h"
#import "BLEControlClass.h"

NSString *srModeUUIDString = @"346D0003-12A9-11CF-1279-81F2B7A91332";

@interface BLEServicesClass() <CBPeripheralDelegate> {

@private
    CBPeripheral        *servicePeripheral;
    CBCharacteristic    *srModeCharacteristic;
@end
```

didDiscoverCharacteristicForService

```
- (void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error;
{

    NSArray     *characteristics    = [service characteristics];
    CBCharacteristic *characteristic;

        if ([[characteristic UUID] isEqual:srModeUUID]) {
            NSLog(@"didDiscoverServices - Mode Characteristic");
            srModeCharacteristic = characteristic;
        }
```

To write to a characteristic

```
-(void)writeCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)whichCharacteristic data:(NSData*)data device:(NSString *)device
{

    NSArray   *devices;
    devices = [[BLEControlClass sharedInstance] connectedPeripherals];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < [[[BLEControlClass sharedInstance] connectedPeripherals] count]; i++) {
        CBPeripheral *peripheral=[[[BLEControlClass sharedInstance] connectedPeripherals] objectAtIndex:i];
        peripheral.delegate=self;
        NSString *tesfordevice = peripheral.name;

        if (tesfordevice == device) {
            [whichCharacteristic.service.peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:whichCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
        }
    }
}
```

This is called by:

```
-(void)writeModeCharacteristic:(NSData*)data :(NSString *)device
{
    [self writeCharacteristic:srModeCharacteristic data:data device:device];
}
```

My issue is that the srModeCharacteristic is initially set correctly when its is discovered but later is NULL.

Any help please?

Comment: Why not store a reference to the peripheral as well as the characteristic to save continually looping. Are you keeping the BLEServices class instances in memory?

Comment: Hi, I loop through a retain list pf peripherals to find the correct data as I'am sending it an NSString with the peripheral name...(hope that makes sense)...Any guidance on retaining the class instance within memory?

Comment: You need to make sure you have a strong reference - either property or iVar  that is holding a reference to your object.  Without seeing more code it isn't possible to say any more as to why the variable is nil

Comment: Okay ... solved the issue. I have saved all the characteristics to an NSMutableDictionary with the peripheral.name as a key. I can then access them and write to them. Thanks for the nudge in the correct direction Paulw11...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend always resolving the characteristics *on demand*, i.e. by iterating and taking the first with the matching UUID. If there are none, issue a new scan – same for the services.

That way your program will easily survive reconnects.

Answer (score 0):

Make a BLE singleton class as i have done in my application. whenever the app is in run state it persist the value of characteristics throughout the app life cycle.